# Pycharm default interpreter and tmp working directory on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pycharm

I use Pycharm for a while now and I'm getting really annoyed that my Pycharm interpreter settings always resets for some reason.

Meaning that whenever I open up a new/old project it will always tell me that:

> No Python interpreter configured...

even after I change and apply the settings in
**File > Settings > Project: ProjectName > Project Interpreter**
or
**File > Default Settings > Project Interpreter**.

(These changes only apply for as long as Pycharm is open. Once it's closed I need to repeat the whole procedure, which is my problem here.)

Then I noticed that all my projects that I open for some reason end up being opened in the tmp folder.
(e.g. "/tmp/Projectname.py")

Which is also the reason why I cant open recent projects via the menu.

So my question is, how do I actually make Pycharm save my interpreter settings and stop asking me about it.

I know that there seems to be similar questions about it, but either they are not solved or the solution doesn't work. And I hope that this tmp folder thing might be of use to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

> how do I actually make Pycharm save my interpreter settings and stop asking me about it.

I was having a similar issue when I used PyCharm Community 2017.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 for the first time. The solution was to open the project folder rather than a specific script.